# Aligning tangents in connecting NURBS-curves

Tags: nurbs-surface

I want to smoothly connect two NURBS-curves. To that purpose, how can I align their common vertex tangents? Right now, they're at an angle (see picture). I could do it manually (on sight), put that would never be (mathematically) perfect. .[image]..

Comment: Thx, but what if one of the objects is not a NURBS-curve, but just an edge.  How can I make the edge coincide with the tangent of the curve's endpoint? Extruding is not possible here

Comment: You don't mention anywhere in your Question that you want tangents between curves an regular Meshes. It's a valid question, but you should be explicit about you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can snap disjoint curves together, and thereby manually make a perfect tangent, then translate that segment away and snap it to the end of one of the Curves. It's easy but isn't exactly obvious..

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You probably joined two nurbs curves, but you still have two independent series of control points (they are drawn in two different colors), each from the original curve joined.

One way is:

- Connect the two near endpoints where the curves should join "perfectly" with a segment (select endpoints and press <kbd>F</kbd>, this creates a segment between them
- now the new segment is selected, subdivide it once, pressing <kbd>W</kbd> (specials) and then choose subdivide
- now select only the joined endpoints (not the new one created by subdivision) and delete them with <kbd>X</kbd> then choose "vertices"

Comment: Thx guys, but what if I want to smoothly join an edge (two vertices) to a NURBS-curve. So this time I want to align the curve's endpoint tangent with the edge, BUT THEY'RE NOT EVEN joinable (or editable at the same time), because the first is a mesh and the second a curve ...

Answer (score 0):

Incidently found an alternative solution on my own. In "Transform Orientations" set the custom axis to the last two control points of the first NURBS, and then use that axis system in the second NURBS to align its control points with those of the first.

Comment: do you mean that you are using a Mesh based object to get your Transform Orientations, and using that in the NURBS curve objects? because NURBS Curve Objects don't expose any orientation information from edge points and segments, only the Curve's matrix.. I don't understand your answer.